# Show $G^2=2\sum o \log \frac{o}{e}$ is approximately $X^2=\sum \frac {(o-e)^2}{e}$

Tags: probability, statistics, taylor-expansion

> Show $G^2=2\sum o \log \frac{o}{e}$ is approximately $X^2=\sum \frac {(o-e)^2}{e}$

$o_i$ = observed $e_i$=expected (I removed $i$'s for ease)

The solution is:

$$G^2=2\sum o \log \frac{o}{e}$$
$$=2\sum e (1+d/e)\log(1+d/e)$$ where $d=o-e$ 
$$=2\sum (d+d^2/2e)=X^2$$

I don't understand these equlaities.

I tried myself to write a $\log$ expansion:

$\log \frac{o}{e}=\log o - \log e$, hence

$$\log o= \log e +(o-e)/e-\frac{(o-e)^2}{2e^2}$$

Then I tried to do some manipulations:

$$\log \frac{o}{e}=\frac{oe-e^2-0.5o^2+oe+0.5e^2}{e^2}$$

$$\log \frac{o}{e}=\frac{2oe-0.5e^2-0.5o^2}{e^2}=-\frac{o^2-4oe+e^2}{2e^2}$$

This is as close as I got
Can you help me?

Comment: The key step uses, for $x=d/e$, the expansion $$(1+x)\log(1+x)=(1+x)(x-x^2/2+o(x^2))=x+x^2/2+o(x^2)$$ and the identity $$\sum d=\sum o-\sum e=1-1=0.$$

Comment: thanks, I understand it now, but I still don't see how I'd come up with it, especially this substitution

Comment: @GRS I don´t understand what you still do not understand.